# Trezor Support for Staked Ethereum Withdrawals?

Tags: staking, trezor, withdrawal

```
Trezor Firmware: v2.6
Trezor App: updated 2023-09-18
```

Since automatic withdrawals started for staked ethereum, I can see on beaconcha.in that they're being credited to my address which is managed by a Trezor device.

The app looks to show the correct overall balance but the history graph does not, instead showing only the accumulated transactions (i.e. neglecting withdrawals which aren't technically "transactions").

*Is this just a bug in the app?*

*Is there something special that needs to be done in order to realize/spend those rewards?*